# Why jar Manifest file shouldn't contain lines with more than 72 bytes

Tags: java, jvm, manifest

I can't find the answer to this on the web.

Line length in the jar manifest length shouldn't exceed 72 bytes, ***why this restriction*** on the line length?

Is it a performance improvement?
Or an old problem that the JVM faced  when it was first released in 1996?

Comment: 72 comes from [ancient ages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_per_line) when there were typewriters... I don't think it was a problem of performances _even_ in 1996 ; maybe a matter of being able to display a manifest on all terminals.

Comment: but we can format the text in any format we want, we can show a text with 72 letters or with 100 letters, we just add few lines of code !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From  [this post](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4842483):

> That said, there is no reason why code that reads manifest files,
>   as in Manifest.java, cannot simply accept input lines of ANY length.
>   The 72-byte restriction is a restriction inherited from RFC 822,
>   but that is a network communication protocol designed for maximal
>   legacy portability for the 70s, which should not be an issue any more.

You are right in that the specification **RFC 822** was made with very very old computer systems in mind. The reason that the restriction still exists however, is because the .jar format is an interchangeable format between different Java implementations, so they are attempting to continue to support the old format for older tools. There is no performance reason anymore however.